# DotNet Core 3 EF 3 with Cosmos DB Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to create an application based on .Net Core 3 and EF Core 3 with the Cosmos DB for database.

I have followed the below steps already,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
}
```

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContextFactory >
    {

        public MyDbContextFactory CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {

            // Get environment
            string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

            // Build config
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var cosmosDbOptions = config.GetSection("CosmosDb").Get<CosmosDbOptions>();
            var (cosmosDbEndpoint, cosmosDbKey, databaseName, collectionData) = cosmosDbOptions;
            var collectionNames = collectionData.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContextFactory>();
            optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(cosmosDbEndpoint, cosmosDbKey, databaseName);

            return new ActivityLoggerContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
```

And

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContextFactory (DbContextOptions<MyDbContextFactory > dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }

    }
```

And when I execute the command,

```
> dotnet ef database update
```

I am getting the below error. Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DesignTimeServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__7(IServiceProvider _)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.EnsureServices(IServiceProvider services)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
**Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception message, you need to configure the database provider when you add your dbcontext service or in your dbcontext's `OnConfiguring` method.

I have got a success by referring the following tutorial: [Using DbContext with dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)

In that tutorial, it uses SqlLite, you can change to use consmos db by adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos`

Comment: Thank you, Jack, Did you get this working for Cosmos Db?

Comment: Yes. You may also refer to: [EF Core Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)